# Drop table that has the name in lower case from the command line

Tags: db2, case-sensitive, database-administration, db2-luw

I need to delete a table that has a lower case name, i.e. `academy`

However when I do `db2 drop table academy` or `db2 drop table "academy"` I get:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "DB2INST1.ACADEMY" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
```

The same command worked for upper case table names though.

When I list my tables I have `> db2 LIST TABLES`

```
Table/View                      Schema          Type  Creation time             
------------------------------- --------------- ----- --------------------------
AA                              DB2INST1        T     2016-06-07-14.23.08.927146
MYNEWTABLE                      DB2INST1        T     2016-06-07-14.29.50.859806
academy                         DB2INST1        T     2016-06-07-17.05.27.510905
```

Comment: It seems when I enter the command line processor, the bug disappears and `drop table "academy" ` returns `DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `db2 drop table "academy"` quotes get swallowed by the shell. You'll need to escape them:

```
db2 drop table \"academy\"
```

or quote the entire statement:

```
db2 'drop table "academy"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a select * from "academy" and see if it will even call the table. If it does you should be able to run the same query again, only replace the word "select" with "drop".